# Problems occur with my Runnable JAR but work fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jar, mouseevent

I am working on an auto-clicker on Eclipse. I've currently coded it so it can click at certain times in between two specified intervals of time.

When I run the program on Eclipse, it will work perfectly fine. The mouse will remain where I left it, and it will click in between the correct intervals.

However, when I export the program as a Runnable JAR it will not work. When I hit "START" on my program and it begins clicking, I will move my mouse. The problem is that when I hit "START" my mouse will jump back to where I pressed the "START" button.

My goal is to have the mouse remain where it is and just click. Does anyone know why this mysterious mouse movement occurs? Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried:

1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR.
2. Package required libraries into generate JAR
3. Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

   ```
   ClickerThread(int startTime, int endTime) throws AWTException {
   ClickerThread.startTime = startTime;
   ClickerThread.endTime = endTime;
   ClickerThread.robot = new Robot();
   }

   @Override
   public synchronized void run() {

   if (!running) {
       running = true;
   }

   while (running) {
       WirbRandomClicker.panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
       System.out.println("Clicking.");
       random_delay = getRandomDelay();
       WirbRandomClicker.txtClickSpeed.setText((random_delay + 10)
               + " milliseconds\n");
       robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
       robot.delay(random_delay);
       robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Google link to common similar questions: [site:stackoverflow.com java works in eclipse but not in jar](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+works+in+eclipse+but+not+in+jar)

Comment: `"I can post code, but I don't believe it will help as there's a good amount of lines."` -- meaning that you're probably here too soon, before you've yet isolated your error. Cut out code, experiment with simple small programs that might use your jar and/or file dependencies until you've isolated the culprit.

Comment: I have been experimenting and Googling. I'm just trying to see if anyone else ran into this odd problem. I may just have to record and X and Y for pixels and have it sit there and click, but my goal was to have it click and be moveable by a human.

Comment: I'll add in the lines where it clicks and delays.

Comment: `"I'm just trying to see if anyone else ran into this odd problem."` -- All. The. F'ing. Time. Please see the links I have provided in the first comment.

Comment: You'll want to add a valid [mcve]. Also does your Jar file have a decent manifest file, one that specifies the correct class-path to your dependent jars?

Comment: Thanks for those links. I checked them out and it appears that one person had a similar problems and was suggested to execute the JAR through terminal/command prompt. I'm honestly fairly new to working with GUI's on Java, there's only two classes involved. I have the classes within a "src" package, which contains a default package, which then contains the two necessary classes.

Comment: Yes if you run it via command line, you'll see any error messages.

Comment: I am getting the error "Unable to access jarfile WirbIntervalClicker.jar". I've tried using "java -jar WirbIntervalClicker.jar". However, if I double click the JAR and open it with "JAR Launcher.app" it opens up, although I have the problem with the mouse moving itself.

Comment: Again have you checked the jar's manifest file's class-path statement?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by that at first. Let me google how to do that and I'll post again with my results.